# Links from wildcard tag search results returning 404

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags, wildcards

## Reproduction

1. Pull up something with a wildcard tag which matches lots of tags.  I ran into this while using the [`django~` tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged?tagnames=django~).
2. Change the sort order to `featured` (or any of the links below `Ask Question`).  For `django~`, you end up at a URL like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged?tagnames=django%20or%20django-models%20or%20django-templates%20or%20django-admin%20or%20django-forms%20or%20django-urls%20or%20django-views%20or%20django-queryset%20or%20django-orm%20or%20django-modelforms%20or%20django-signals%20or%20django-authentication%20or%20django-flatpages%20or%20django-queries%20or%20django-syncdb%20or%20django-middleware%20or%20django-managers%20or%20django-apps%20or%20django-formsets%20or%20django-testing%20or%20django-tagging%20or%20django-comments%20or%20django-mptt%20or%20django-model%20or%20django-modelformsets%20or%20django-imagefield%20or%20django-aggregation%20or%20django-generic-views%20or%20django-cms%20or%20django-fields%20or%20django-validation%20or%20django-widgets%20or%20django-template-tags%20or%20django-file-upload%20or%20django-haystack%20or%20django-cache%20or%20django-filter%20or%20django-database%20or%20django-profiles%20or%20django-sphinx%20or%20django-select-related%20or%20django-sessions%20or%20django-rss%20or%20django-contrib%20or%20django-permissions%20or%20django-syndication%20or%20django-mailer%20or%20django-wsgi%20or%20django-voting%20or%20django-template%20or%20django-templatetags%20or%20django-treebeard%20or%20django-trunk%20or%20django-widget%20or%20django-manage.py%20or%20django-inheritance%20or%20django-multilingual%20or%20django-pagination%20or%20django-notifcation%20or%20django-sites%20or%20django-south%20or%20django-project-architect%20or%20django-pyodbc%20or%20django-search-lucene%20or%20django-custom-tag%20or%20django-custom-tags%20or%20django-1.1%20or%20django-email%20or%20django-formwizard%20or%20django-generic-formset%20or%20django-history%20or%20django-hosting%20or%20django-groups%20or%20django-errors%20or%20django-exceptions%20or%20django-development-server%20or%20django-dispatch%20or%20django-ajax-selects%20or%20django-atom%20or%20django-content-type%20or%20django-contrib-formtools%20or%20django-contrib-markup%20or%20django-csrf%20or%20django-registration%20or%20django-rest-interface%20or%20django-settings%20or%20django-openid-auth%20or%20django-permalink%20or%20django-multi-table-inheri%20or%20django-model-history%20or%20django-tutorials%20or%20django-uni-form%20or%20django-uploads%20or&sort=featured&pagesize=15).

   - The response headers indicate a 404 response, even though the page is blank.
   - ### The URL is 2,262 characters long, which the browser and/or server doesn't handle well.

     Microsoft has [documented](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/208427/EN-US) their maximum URL length in IE at 2,083 characters.  I don't know if other browsers have different limitations, but Firefox and Safari both receive 404 errors.
   - If you do this on wildcard tags which match much fewer tags, such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged?tagnames=python%20or%20python-3.x%20or%20pythonic%20or%20python-2.6%20or%20python-c-api%20or%20python-datamodel%20or%20python-mysqldb%20or%20python-2.5%20or%20python-2.x%20or%20python-module%20or%20pythoncard%20or%20pythonpath%20or%20python-2.4%20or%20python-interpreter%20or%20python-mode%20or%20python-decorators%20or%20python-egg-cache%20or%20python-embedding%20or%20python-3.1%20or%20python-c-extension%20or%20python-path%20or%20pythonw%20or%20python-socketserver%20or%20python-visual%20or%20python-svn-swig-api%20or%20python-time%20or%20python-twitter%20or%20pythonce%20or%20python-2.1%20or%20python-imaging-library%20or%20python-import%20or%20python-install%20or%20python-gil%20or%20pythonian%20or%20python-design-patterns%20or%20pythonista%20or%20python-nose%20or%20python-openid%20or%20python-2.2.3%20or%20python-2.3%20or%20python3%20or%20python2.6%20or%20python-challenge%20or%20python-api%20or%20python-uno%20or%20python-server-pages%20or%20python-slots%20or%20python-standard-library%20or%20pythonwin%20or&sort=featured&pagesize=15) (for [`python~`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged?tagnames=python~)), everything works as expected.

## Solution?

The first thing that came to my mind was to reuse the `tagname` being passed in.  When constructing links, use a sanitized version of the original `tagname` string.  The current functionality appears to construct the URL using the tags which resulted from the search.  Using the original `tagname` string would result in a URL like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged?tagnames=django~&sort=featured) (shown below), when clicking on `featured` under `django~`.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged?tagnames=django~&sort=featured

Comment: +1 for explicit steps to reproduce.

Answer (score 3):

I now limit the number of tags that can come back from a wildcard explode operation, so this is fixed.

*Update:* Links are now generated with the wildcard intact, for example:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged?tagnames=django*&sort=featured

Comment: What is the limit (so I can add it to the FAQ entry, which I just modified)?

Comment: Doesn't that mean that a result I'm really interested in can go missing because its tag got lobbed off?

Answer (score 0):

I think someone should instead combine django tags so the list isn't so long, or the system should recognize when its wildcard matches result in too long a query string and disallow such broad wildcard matches.

Comment: I have to agree, the list of tags matched by `django~` is quite excessive, but I think the issue is easily solved without resorting to disallowing a search.  Also, look at this from the vantage point of Stack Exchange, where a client may have a search resulting in only 20 tags, but each one is 100 characters long (as excessive as this may be).